# May I install Ubuntu and Debian sharing the same swap memory?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, swap, debian

I want to install Debian and Ubuntu in the same disk with different partitions.
I also have a windows partition.

The question is if I could install Ubuntu and Debian sharing the same swap memory or instead I need to have one swap partition for each installation.

Has anyone tried this?